# Prevent newly created click event from running

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Here's a simplified example of the problem I'm having. Say I have this HTML:

```
<div id="test">Hello</div>
```

I have the following event handler attached to this `div`:

```
$("#test").on("click", function() {
    console.log("Clicked test!");

    $(document).one("click", function() {
        console.log("Clicked on document!");
    });
});
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qm5fw3ok/) of this example.

If I click on <kbd>Hello</kbd>, ideally I would only want "Clicked test!" to appear in my console, and for "Clicked on document!" to appear after I click a second time. However, both log messages appear, as the click event bubbles up to the `document` object and runs this new click event. Is there a way to prevent this from happening without using `stopPropagation`, which may have other unintended side effects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution is kind of hacky, but it does work.  If you set the document click handler asynchonously, the event doesn't bubble up:

```
$("#test").on("click", function(e) {
    console.log("Clicked test!");

    setTimeout(function(){
        $(document).one("click", function() {
            console.log("Clicked on document!");
        });
    }, 10);

    return true;
});
```

See the modified fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/voveson/qm5fw3ok/2/

Comment: Isn't this only dependent on the event bubbling up fast enough? What if you had a huge document and `#test` is buried somewhere, or what if your browser is lagging--wouldn't it be possible that the document `click` handler still runs?

Comment: The "return true" marks the event as handled, so as long as the timeout function doesn't run before that line executes, you'll be fine.  You can increase the timeout value if it concerns you, but this should really be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Or using on and off with selectors:

```
$(document).on("click", "#test", add_doc_click)

function add_doc_click() {
    console.log("Clicked test!");
    $(document).on("click", function (e) {

        console.log("Clicked on document!");
    })
    $(document).off("click", "#test", add_doc_click)

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y2q1gocu/

EDIT: to have test and clicked each time:

```
$(document).on("click", "#test", add_doc_click)

function add_doc_click() {
    console.log("Clicked test!");
    $(document).on("click", function (e) {

        console.log("Clicked on document!");

    })
    $(document).on("click", "#test", function (e) {

        console.log("Clicked test!");

    })
    $(document).off("click", "#test", add_doc_click)

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y2q1gocu/1/

Comment: This doesn't seem to provide the desired functionality.  The line "clicked test!" only is printed the first time test is clicked.  Thereafter, only "clicked on document!" is printed.

Comment: Oh, I thought that it was what you wanted. See edit, it's a bit more complicated then, but still works.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming nothing should happen on the third click, add these two lines at the end of the `click` handler:

```
$(this).off('click');
return false;
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/0rhwhLr8/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class that flags whether or not the element has been clicked on or not.

```
$("#test").on("click", function(e) {
    console.log("Clicked test!");

    if($(this).hasClass('clicked')){
        $(document).one("click", function(e) {
            console.log("Clicked on document!");
        });
    }else{
         $(this).addClass('clicked');   
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Incase you want to click Hello once and then remaining on document.

```
$( "div" ).one( "click", function() {
console.log("Clicked test!");
    event.stopPropagation();
});

 $(document).on("click", function() {
        console.log("Clicked on document!");
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qm5fw3ok/3/